# How to change time and battery color on iOS with flutter no AppBar

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I want to change the color of the status bar on iOS so that when I make the background black you can still see the time and battery. I have seen solutions for if you have an AppBar however I'm not using an AppBar in my app.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Code I have so far

[image]

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how to do it in flutter, but there are native iOS methods to do it. Presumably there is some way to call the native api from flutter. https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-set-status-bar-style/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an `AppBar` you can try adding a `Container` to the `SafeArea`, and set a different colour for the container than the background colour. In the following code I use yellow and red to see clearly the different areas. Please note the `left`, `top` etc. configs. This is how you can control which sides are protected by `SafeArea`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
    body: SafeArea(
      left: false,
      top: true,
      right: false,
      bottom: true,
      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
    ),
  );
}
```

So the solution to your original problem can be something like below. I commented out `backgroundColor` because this way it is the phone default, but you can add any colour you like.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    //backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
    body: SafeArea(
      left: false,
      top: true,
      right: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: Container(color: Colors.black),
    ),
  );
}
```